# Eclipse Web-App Deployment with Tomcat: Providing multiple projects' dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a problem providing some third party librarys (JAR-files) I am using when deploying my dynamic web application with Tomcat 6 and Eclipse.

*Please note that I -do know- how to do this in a setup, where the web application project -directly- depends on those JARs.*

However, in my setup, I have two Eclipse projects:

- **core** is a class library and depends on, lets say, `a.jar`.
- **web** is the web application and depends on **core**.

In the project settings of **web**, in the *Deployment Assembly* category, I have added **core**, so Eclipse (or Tomcat - I'm not quite sure who the responsible actor here is) is putting `core.jar` into the `libs` directory of my web application.

The problem is: When I try out the web application, a `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown when **core** accesses classes from `a.jar`. What am I supposed to do about this? I don't think that putting `a.jar` into the *Deployment Assembly* settings page of my web application is the right solution, since it should be of no relevance to the **web** project, what the **core** project depends on.

Basically, I am looking for a way to configure Eclipse (Tomcat?) to 'embed' the dependencies of **core** into `core.jar`. The problem about this is, that `core.jar` is generated automatically, when I deploy my **web** project.

Help is very appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I've found the answer on my own meanwhile.

For those reading this in the future I will explain step by step, using the semantics I introduced in [my original message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11081411/1444073):

First, open the properties page of your **core** project and navigate to the 'Libraries' tab of the 'Java Build Path' settings:

[image]

Make sure to add your class library `a.jar`, your **core** project depends on, via 'Add JARs...'. Then, go ahead to the 'Order and Export' tab and activate the just added `a.jar` for exporting.

[image]

Then go to the 'Deployment Assembly' settings and also add `a.jar` here by first clicking on 'Add...', then on 'Java Build Path Entries' and finally selecting `a.jar`. Make sure to enter '../' as the deploy path for `a.jar`:

[image]

Now you are done with your **core** project. Now open the 'Projects' page of the 'Java Build Path' settings for your **web** project and add your **core** project by clicking on 'Add...':

[image]

Finally, navigate to the 'Deployment Assembly' settings page, press 'Add...', then take 'Project' and select your **core** project on the next screen:

[image]

You're done. No need to add your **core** dependencies to your **web** project.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know eclipse doesn't do it for you. Project dependencies are for compile time. Runtime dependencies that span across projects should be handled by you. One trick you can use to create user libraries. Go to preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User libraries. Create a new user library. Add all the jars that your 'core' project depends on. Add it as a dependency to both 'core' and 'web' projects. To do that,, right click on project -> Build Path -> Configure build path -> Libraries tab -> Add Library...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) which will automatically compiles the `jar` files for you and `Eclipse` works with `Maven` very well too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Gradle-Project make sure, you have the "eclipse-wtp" Plugin in your build.gradle's of the Sub-Projects.