# Add Eclipse project to Tomcat classpath

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, buildpath

I have two Eclipse projects A, B. I add a dependency of B to A. At compile time everything is fine. I added B to the build path of A. 
However, when I deploy A to Tomcat I get a ClassNotFound exception  of a Class which is defined in A. I followed all possible solutions I found around:

[Tomcat throws ClassNotFound exceptions for classes in other open eclipse projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603758/tomcat-throws-classnotfound-exceptions-for-classes-in-other-open-eclipse-project)

[Eclipse Web-App Deployment with Tomcat: Providing multiple projects' dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081411/eclipse-web-app-deployment-with-tomcat-providing-multiple-projects-dependencie)

http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/11/12/adding-multiple-eclipse-projects-to-tomc

However, nothing seems to work. Anybody has an idea

Comment: Because what's available on the server might not be exposed to Eclipse, as well as for situations like this, you should look into the `Deployment Assembly` property page of project A. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27086_05/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.doc/html/files/extresProjectConfig.html

Comment: Nitind, I tried that as well but didnt work. The thing is that project B also depends on some external jars. Do i specifically need to add them in project  A as well? Well, Acually I did that as well but again didnt work ... I ran out of ideas